# In Bash, I am moving $File from $Dir1 to $Dir2. How do I tell Bash to look for the filename of $File in $Dir3 and move it to $Dir1?

Tags: bash, find

I have a process that watches $Dir2 for files, processes them, and moves the file to $Dir3.  So my task is to find files for processing and return them back to source when done:

- Move one file from $Dir1 to $Dir2
- Wait for it to not appear in $Dir2
- Check for the file in $Dir3
- If found, move the file back to $Dir1

Some notes:

- Each file has a unique file path
- Each file has a unique name
- It's possible for $Dir1, $Dir2. and $Dir3 to have multiple files in the directory
- This larger loop would loop for infinity

What I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the directories
dir1="/path/to/origin/directory"
dir2="/path/to/destination/directory"
dir3="/path/to/watch/directory"

# Find the files in the origin directory
files=$(find "$dir1" -type f)

# Loop through the files
for file in $files
do
  # Move the file to the destination directory
  mv "$file" "$dir2"

  # Need to loop through $dir2
    #when $file is not in $dir2, check to see if $file is in $dir3
      #If $file is in $dir3, move file to $dir1  

    #Done

  mv "$file" "$dir1"
done
```

In Bash, how do I look for the filename of $file in $Dir3?

Comment: Note that this code won't work if any of the filenames contain spaces, it will be split into multiple items in the `for` loop.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F001.How_can_I_read_a_file_.28data_stream.2C_variable.29_line-by-line_.28and.2For_field-by-field.29.3F

Comment: Don't use a scalar variable for `files=$(find "$dir1" -type f)`, use an array, and then `for file in $files` becomes the more robust `for file in "${files[@]}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's substitution operator to replace `$dir1` with `$dir3` in the filename.

```
for file in $files
do
    ...
    $file3=${file/$dir1/$dir3}
    if [ -f "$file3" ]
    then
        # do something
    fi
    ...
done
```